# How to transfer data from a newer to an older MS SQL server using cmd?

Tags: sql-server, database, import, cmd, export

I have a database server (let's call it S) with some data running **MS SQL 2012**. On the other end of the world there are tablets running MS SQL 2012 EXPRESS (let's call them TS). A part of the data must be transferred from S to TS. Due to many reasons the only way to communicate is to send files from S to proxy servers to have them picked up by TS later.

Currently I'm using backup files (.BAK) so I can simply create a partial backup of S' database and restore it on TS.

Now here is the problem:

It might happen that in a while S will switch to **MS SQL 2014**. It's not possible to install 2014 on TS because I have no direct access to them. In this case S will still be able to restore data created with SQL 2012 on TS but not the other way around because it's impossible to restore backups from a newer SQL version on an older one. So this is the point I need help in.

I've tried to **export** the data using the server management tool on S instead of creating a backup and import everything on TS. This works well but the export must happen automatically per **command line**. The good old **sqlpubwiz** is not an option because it was discontinued and only works up to version 2008 R2.

So I need ideas how to export from S using cmd/powershell and import on TS only using files to communicate even if they are running different versions of MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Powershell does the trick but it was way too slow. At the end I've still used BCP. BCP means a lot of scripting to do but works about 30 times faster than using powershell. However, here is the powershell script I've used:

```
set-psdebug -strict
$DirectoryToSaveTo='...' #path where to save the data
$ServerName='...' #Hostname\Instance
$Database='...' #database to export
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
Trap {
    $err = $_.Exception
    write-host $err.Message
    while( $err.InnerException ) {
        $err = $err.InnerException
        write-host $err.Message
    };
    break
}
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')
if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended') | out-null
}
$My='Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo'
$s = new-object ("$My.Server") $ServerName
$Server=$s.netname -replace '[\\\/\:\.]',' '
$instance = $s.instanceName -replace '[\\\/\:\.]',' '
$DatabaseName =$database -replace '[\\\/\:\.]',' '
$DirectoryToSaveTo=$DirectoryToSaveTo+'\'+$Instance+'\'
$CreationScriptOptions = new-object ("$My.ScriptingOptions")
$CreationScriptOptions.ExtendedProperties= $true
$CreationScriptOptions.DRIAll= $true
$CreationScriptOptions.Indexes= $true
$CreationScriptOptions.Triggers= $true
$CreationScriptOptions.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true
$CreationScriptOptions.Filename = "$($DatabaseName)_Schema.sql";
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeHeaders = $true;
$CreationScriptOptions.ToFileOnly = $true # no need of string output as well
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeIfNotExists = $true # not necessary but it means the script can be more versatile
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $s.Databases[$Database]
$transfer.options=$CreationScriptOptions # tell the transfer object of our preferences
$scripter = new-object ("$My.Scripter") $s # script out the database creation
$scripter.options=$CreationScriptOptions # with the same options
$scripter.Script($s.Databases[$Database]) # do it
"USE $Database" | Out-File -Append -FilePath "$($DatabaseName)_Schema.sql"
"GO" | Out-File -Append -FilePath "$($DatabaseName)_Schema.sql"
$transfer.options.AppendToFile=$true
$transfer.options.ScriptDrops=$true
$transfer.EnumScriptTransfer()
$transfer.options.ScriptDrops=$false
$transfer.EnumScriptTransfer()
"All written to $($DatabaseName)_Schema.sql"
```

This script exports only the schema but it should be quite obvious how to export also all the data.

Answer (score 1):

I've used detatched databases before to distribute databases to laptops before. They are much quicker to import than a backup, but I'm not sure about inter-version compatibility.

You could write a tool that you package up as an exe that contains CSV files and a loader script which uses Bcp.exe

Comment: Tank you. Detracted databases are also affected by the version conflict :( Your second point might work but it's a lot of trouble to export hundreds of tables and all the data. In addition I don't know what the database will look like in a year, there might be new tables. This is a solution I'll take if there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using the built-in replication features, setting up S as a snapshot replication publisher, and TS as a subscriber via FTP. SQL Server Express can act as a subscriber (but not a published) in a replication scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832.aspx

If you want to write a more intricate scenario, you may want to consider [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sync/bb736753.aspx)

Comment: Publisher/subscriber means that S and TS must communicate directly, right? This is not possible :(

Comment: @MichaelS Snapshot can be delivered via FTP. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146956(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: FTP is not running/allowed on the proxy servers. Furthermore there would be still a version conflict. :(

Comment: @MichaelS Then how are you transferring the files? Snapshot replication can work across DB versions.

Comment: We are transferring the files using our own services in S and our proxy. The communication is encrypted.